How to console.log at the library's typescript file when running test?
I want to debug my typescript code which uses plenty of libraries. I want to console.log at the library's typescript code, so I can see what's going on at the under the hood. I added console.log at the library code, but when I run test of my code, it's console doesn't print. How could I do this?

If you really edited the typescript code, you probable need to recompile it, because most runtimes execute the compiled javascript code and not the typescript code. But to be able to help you, you need to tell us a bit more about your environment. Ie what runtime are you using, what library are you talking about, ...

@derpirscher I'm using ts-mocha for test. And the command I use is the specific framework's test command. FYI, it is like this. anchor test. At this framework's toml file, the test script's specific command is like this. yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts. So at my case, how could I rebuild the already built library code installed at the node_modules?

How to build the library should be part of the libraries documentation. But probably it's easier to edit the compiled JS of the library instead

@derpirscher Ah, so you mean the build rules may be different between libraries. Ok, it looks good idea to find the js file to console log. Thanks a lot

Well every library has specific requirements on how it's built. There may be dev-dependencies that are not installed by default, specific steps that need to be followed, ...
